COM Port Availability
I am looking for a way to obtain a list of available COM ports that can be used in a PC. I am planning on using PowerShell. I have the following question as reference:
Reference 1
This question showed me that I was able to see the COM Ports currently in use on my PC. However, if I wanted to change or create another object with a new COM Port how I would like to see what the numbers are I could choose for a COM port on a PC. For example, if 3, and 4 how do I know which port numbers are available for usage like can I use 5, 6, or even 30? Overall, I am aiming to avoid COM Port Conflict when assigning COM Ports.

What are the specifications on the device that will support COM communication? You typically achieve that with some sort of USB device. When connected those ports should show up in Device Manager.
